# android detect if a dialog is active?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

Is there a generic way to determine if there is dialog currently shown ?  Sure, i can keep track of all `createDialog` and `dismissDialog` invocations, but that's cumbersome.

thanks

Comment: This seems like something you should know... How are you creating dialogs and not knowing whether they're displayed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method:

```
protected void showDialogSafe(int id) {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        showDialog(id);
    }
}
```

Which I grabbed from here: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/activities-and-dialogs.html

When dismissing them I just catch the IllegalArgumentException.

Falmarri, keeping track of the dialogs seems to be easier said than done when you have multiple threads running.  I thought my code was perfect, but I get a bunch of crash reports when my app tries to dismiss dialogs that aren't shown or tries to display a dialog when the activity is finished.